# Camera2Basic app front camera takes pic upside down

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

I have tried Google's [android-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) sample app. For front camera get works, I have changed some code in [Camera2BasicFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java). The changes are as follows.

To switch to front camera I have changed `mCameraId = cameraId;` to `mCameraId = "1";` in `setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height)` method.

And added on if condition at end of `setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height)` like,

```
if(mCameraId == null)
    mCameraId = cameraId;
```

This change shows front camera perfectly but doesn't pick the photo. So I replaced

```
mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback,
                        mBackgroundHandler);
```

to

```
captureStillPicture();
```

in `lockFocus()`. Now front camera picks the photo, but it looks upside down.

For ex:

[image: sample image]

I don't know what to do now.

My requirement is to capture photo in both cameras using camera2 api. So if I did anything wrong please correct me.

And in some devices this app takes more than one pic on single click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the below condition and initialize the default camera globally and also remove the for loop.

```
if(mCameraId == null) {
   mCameraId = cameraId;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just removed the `for` loop from `setUpCameraOutputs` 
And also removed the `if(mCameraId == null) mCameraId = cameraId;`.

Now issue is fixed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

easiest solution is

> captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 0);